# Фон для параллакса

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, sass, веб-дизайн

Всем привет!

Мне нужно подготовить дизайн для бэкграунда сайта, зная о технических органичениях.
На фоне будет изображены множество маленьких звезд (много овалов белого цвета), которые при скролле будут создавать эффект параллакса и объема.
Подготовленный файл png, который был по размеру 5000х5000px (размер такой сделан, чтобы и на ретине хорошо смотрелось) очень много весит и тормозит сайт.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно другими способами сделать такой фон, чтобы к нему можно было применить парралакс, хорошее качество на ретине.

Comment: Используйте векторную графику (svg). Она отлично подходит для простых фигур, мало весит и прекрасно смотрится на retina - дисплеях.

Comment: Если звёзды расположены хаотично, я бы подготовил меньшее изображение и повторял его. Главное - добиться бесшовности и визуальной равномерности.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Взять все уникальные звезды, сделать из них спрайт и создать блок, в который добавить рандомно блоки с фоновым изображением из этих самых звезд. Псевдокод будет таким:

```css
.parallax {
  position: relative;
}

.parallax__star {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(images/stars.png);
}

.parallax__star--2 {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-position: 100% 0;
}

.parallax__star--3 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}

.parallax__star--4 {
  top: 80;
  left: 20%;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__star parallax__star--1"></div>
  <div class="parallax__star parallax__star--2"></div>
  <div class="parallax__star parallax__star--3"></div>
  <div class="parallax__star parallax__star--4"></div>
</div>
```

2. Сделать то же самое, но собрать SVG-спрайт.
3. Если эти варианты точно не подходят (что маловероятно), то хотя бы оптимизировать графику через, например, [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/). Но оптимизировать графику надо в любом случае, даже для первых двух вариантов.